# Side navigation scroll icons are not appearing even if the content height is more than screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am using **sap.tnt.SideNavigation** in order to create side panel.For that i am creating a page and the page has **sap.tnt.SideNavigation** which consist of navigation items to display in side navigation.So the xml view is like this,

```
<Page>
<content>
<m:ToggleButton icon="sap-icon://menu2" press="onCollapseExapandPress"/>
            <SideNavigation id="sideNavigation" visible="false">
                <item>
                    <NavigationList itemSelect="onItemSelect" items="{path:'/widgetsToLoad/widgets'}">
                        <NavigationListItem icon="{icon}" visible="{inPanel}"
                            tooltip="{name}"></NavigationListItem>
                    </NavigationList>
                </item>
            </SideNavigation>
</content>
</Page>
```

After doing this eventhough the content height is nore than screen height it will not show scroll icons instead scroll bar will come.How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [sap.tnt.SideNavigation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.tnt.SideNavigation/about) should be used only with [sap.tnt.ToolPage](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.tnt.ToolPage/about) as parent layout control. Thus it might not work perfectly within a Page control.

In general the scroll items are shown if the SideNavigation is not expanded, otherwise the scroll bar is shown. You can check this by playing around with the [ToolPage example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.tnt.ToolPage/about).

Comment: I have used it, Side navigation panel will work but if navigation bar content is more it will not show scroll icons.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @matbtt can't we customize SideNavigation colours? with a custom CSS?

Comment: You may read the documentation about custom CSS: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796